# Oracle OpenScript "Error reading file" when substituting variable

Tags: java, oracle, scripting, openscript

I'm composing a web script with Oracle OpenScript.

I recorded the actions to be performed

- open link
- select drop-down menu
- select field from drop-down menu
- save

and I'm trying to now substitute the link to be opened with a variable from a .csv I created in the assets but I get a "Error reading file" message.

[**SCREENSHOT**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAgyQ.png)

Here's the full code:

```
import oracle.oats.scripting.modules.basic.api.*;
import oracle.oats.scripting.modules.browser.api.*;
import oracle.oats.scripting.modules.functionalTest.api.*;
import oracle.oats.scripting.modules.utilities.api.*;
import oracle.oats.scripting.modules.utilities.api.sql.*;
import oracle.oats.scripting.modules.utilities.api.xml.*;
import oracle.oats.scripting.modules.utilities.api.file.*;
import oracle.oats.scripting.modules.webdom.api.*;

public class script extends IteratingVUserScript {
@ScriptService oracle.oats.scripting.modules.utilities.api.UtilitiesService 
utilities;
@ScriptService oracle.oats.scripting.modules.browser.api.BrowserService 
browser;
@ScriptService 
oracle.oats.scripting.modules.functionalTest.api.FunctionalTestService ft;
@ScriptService oracle.oats.scripting.modules.webdom.api.WebDomService web;

public void initialize() throws Exception {
    browser.launch();
}

/**
 * Add code to be executed each iteration for this virtual user.
 */
public void run() throws Exception {
    beginStep("[1] No Title (/hotelconfig.html)", 0);
    {
        web.window(2, "/web:window[@index='0' or @title='about:blank']")
                .navigate(
                        "URL");
        {
            think(0.093);
        }
    }
    endStep();
    beginStep("[2] Working... (/wia)", 0);
    {
        web.window(4, "/web:window[@index='0' or @title='about:blank']")
                .navigate(
                        "URL");
        web.window(
                5,
                "/web:window[@index='0']")
                .waitForPage(null);
        {
            think(6.198);
        }
        web.selectBox(
                6,
                "/web:window[@index='0']/web:document[@index='0']/web:form[@index='0']/web:select[(@id='office_id' or @name='office_id' or @index='10') and multiple mod 'False']")
                .selectOptionByText(
                        "Office");
        {
            think(2.636);
        }
        web.button(
                7,
                "/web:window[@index='0']/web:document[@index='0']/web:form[@index='0']/web:input_submit[@name='save' or @value='Save' or @index='0']")
                .click();
    }
    endStep();
    beginStep(
            "[3] Intranet - Property info - *Hotel Settings - *Hotel configuration (/hotelconfig.html)",
            0);
    {
        web.window(
                8,
                "/web:window[@index='0']")
                .waitForPage(null);
    }
    endStep();

}

public void finish() throws Exception {
}
}
```

I looked online and on Oracle's community but I couldn't find a fix.
I also tried to run the OpenScript Diagnosis Tool but no luck.

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Did you add at least one column and one row of data to your file? You can use excel or any text editor. File must be plain text.

Comment: yes, of course. The .csv I use is URL,Office in each column, complete with headers. I tried to create the .csv from within OpenScript, from Excel and also from Notepad but I always get the error. The .csv is saved in the script's folder and is set as "relative to current script"

Answer (score 1):

Oracle Application Testing Suite (OATS) best supports csv data sheet reading. 
Code you pasted is just recording you performed and not seen any issue there. and Screenshot shows error message, something might have gone wrong while creating csv.

I can suggest external excel reader , which is inbuilt in OATS itself
http://www.testinghive.com/category/oracle-application-testing-suite-tips/

```
//Define Sheet name to be read, and provide comma seperated to read multiple sheets
String sheetName = "Sheet1";
//Mention excel sheet path
String strFile= "C:\\Demo\\test.xls";

//Defined array list to add Sheets to read
List sheetList = new ArrayList();
sheetList.add(sheetName);
// Iports Sheet1
datatable.importSheets(strFile, sheetList, true, true);
//get rowcount
info("Total rows :"+datatable.getRowCount());
int rowcount=datatable.getRowCount();
//Loop to read all rows
for (int i=0;i<rowcount;i++)
{
//Set current row fromw here you need to start reading, in this case start from first row
datatable.setCurrentRow(sheetName, i);
String strCompany=(String) datatable.getValue(sheetName,i,"Company");
String strEmpFName=(String) datatable.getValue(sheetName,i,"FirstName");
String strEmpLName=(String) datatable.getValue(sheetName,i,"LastName");
String strEmpID=(String) datatable.getValue(sheetName,i,"EmpID");
String strLocation=(String) datatable.getValue(sheetName,i,"Location");

//prints first name and last name
System.out.println("First Name : "+strEmpFName+", Last Name : "+strEmpLName);

//Sets ACTIVE column in excel sheet to Y
String strActive="Y";
datatable.setValue(sheetName, i, datatable.getColumn(sheetName, datatable.getColumnIndex("Active")), strActive);

}

//Updates sheet with updated values ie ACTIVE column sets to Y
datatable.exportToExcel("C:\\Demo\\test1.xlsx");

}

public void finish() throws Exception {
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it easier to use a databank as data provider.

By adding a CSV file with the necessary variable, you will be able to do the following substitution:

```
public void run() throws Exception {    
    getDatabank("databank").getNextDatabankRecord();
    String v_dataFilename = "{{db.databank.filename}}";
}
```